# How do I Select an aggregate function from a temp table without getting the invalid column error from not including the column in the GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, temp-tables

I performed aggregate functions in a `temp table` but I'm getting an error because the field I performed the aggregate function on is not included in a `GROUP BY` in the table I am selecting from. To clarify, this is just a snippet so these tables are temp tables in the larger query. They are also named in the actual code.

```
WITH #t1 AS
(SELECT
  Name,
  Date,
  COUNT(Email),
  COUNT(DISTINCT Email)
FROM SentEmails)
SELECT
  #t1.*,
  #t2.GrossSents
FROM #t1
--***JOINS***
GROUP BY
  #t1.Name,
  #t1.Date
```

I expect a table with `Name`, `Date`, `Count of Emails`, `Unique Emails`, and `Gross Sends` fields but I get

> Column '#t1.COUNT(Email)' is invalid in the select list` because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Don't start the names of your CTE's with a hash (`#`). The `#` character is used to denote a temporary table object. A CTE is **not** a temporary table, or even an object, it is ,as the name suggests, a Common Table *Expression*.

Comment: The problem you have here, however, is that you appear to be  trying to perform aggregation in your CTE, but put the `GROUP BY` in your final `SELECT` statement. Either the `GROUP BY` clause needs to be moved to the CTE, or the aggregation moved to the final `SELECT`. That need to be in the same resultset declaration, not different ones.

Comment: Can you please add your sample data with expected output from them?

Comment: Also, you should give the aggregate column alias names in the CTE.  Such as COUNT(email) AS email_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your issue into steps.

Start by getting the query inside your `CTE` to return the data you expect from it. The query as written here won't run because you're doing aggregation without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Once that query is giving you the results you want, wrap it in the `CTE` syntax and try a `SELECT * FROM cteName` to see if that works. You'll get an error here because each column in a `CTE` has to have a name and your last two columns don't have names. Also, as noted in the comments, it's a poor practice to name your `CTE` with a `#`. It makes the subsequent code more confusing, since it appears as though there's a temp table someplace, and there isn't.

After you have the `CTE` returning what you need, start joining other tables, one at a time. Monitor those results as you add tables so you're sure that your `JOIN`s are working as you expect.

If you're doing further aggregation on the outer query, specifying `SELECT *` is just asking for trouble because you're going to need to specify every non-aggregated column in your `GROUP BY` anyway. As a general rule, you should enumerate your columns in your `SELECT`, and in this case that will allow you to copy & paste them to your eventual `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This did it. I had GROUP BY in both the temp tables I was creating to join as well as after I joined them. I removed the GROUP BY after the join and it worked fine. I left the ORDER BY. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped.